# Where to find authentic weather data for local regions?

Tags: database, weather

I am working on geo-spatial interpolation project. For this project, I require historical weather data for small cities in Pakistan,like , Kakul, Balakot and Muzaffarabad. I tried to find data but could not get authentic data source. Can anyone please guide me in this regard??

P.S. From authentic data, I mean data collected on the spot not any interpolated or estimated data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a data source not relevant to SO

Comment: This is an interesting/good question but is not relevant to SO.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200984/where-can-i-find-historical-raw-weather-data @Peter Smith, this type of questions are already being answered on SO, just not covering my region of interest

Comment: That question was closed 5 years ago as off-topic. SO is about programming.